# Accessing to a wcf service

Tags: wcf

i have a problem.
I tried to access to the wcf web service from an application ASP.net MVC, I got this exception when I am calling the method.

> There was no endpoint listening at the URI   that could accept the
>   message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.
>   See InnerException, if present, for more details.

this is my code

```
var client = new DSServiceClient();
client.Methode();
```

service model section of web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDSService" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="localhost:1695/Service1.svc"; binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IDSService" contract="ServiceReference1.IDSService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IDSService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Your code is fine _if_ there's an endpoint listening on the address you have specified in your app.config and _if_ that endpoint interface exposes a method named `Methode`.

Comment: FYI, it's "a WCF Service", not "a WCF"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my web.config of the service

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpEndpointBinding">
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
        realm="" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="DSWebService.Service1Behavior"
    name="DSWebService.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"
      contract="DSWebService.IDSService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:1695/DSWebService" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DSWebService.Service1Behavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

and this is my web.config of the client:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IDSService" />
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:1695/Service1.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IDSService" contract="IDSService"
      name="WSHttpBinding_IDSService">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

and the 2 project should be on the same solution and after we do add reference :

```
DSServiceClient client = new DSServiceClient();
```

client.Methode();

Answer (score 0):

Check that the URL you are using is accessible from asp.net mvc site. If you are using http binding you can copy and paste url into browser on the server where your site is deployed. The URL should be in web.config file in the root folder of your site.

Comment: <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDSService" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:1695/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IDSService" contract="ServiceReference1.IDSService"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IDSService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>

Comment: when i copy and paste it was a slash on the end i don't know and the response is endpoint not found.

Comment: if you open your browser, and visit http://localhost:1695/Service1.svc what do you get?

Comment: So, when i run my service from vs2012 right-click on the Service.svc and run on the browser,it's ok.also when I visit localhost:1695/Service1.svc/Methode1 it's OK.Also when I host the service in IIs it's OK.

Comment: But the problem is when I call the methode in ClientProject

Answer (score 0):

Are you using IIS 7 to host? If So you can go to your site, enable directory browsing (temporarily), click on the browse link on the right side of IIS manager, select the service class ("something.svc") and it should pop up in a browser. At that point you can copy the URL from the browser and replace localhost with the server name. You can even go on to click on the top link on that page to get to the WSDL. If there is a problem you may get an error message that may be more helpful.

Comment: I don't found the browse link .:(

Comment: Erreur HTTP 404.3 - Not Found
La page que vous avez demandée ne peut pas être traitée en raison de la configuration d'extension. Si la page est un script, ajoutez un gestionnaire. Si le fichier doit être téléchargé, ajoutez un mappage MIME.

Comment: Now you should know what the URL is, mais j'ai pas vraiment comprise la message d'error , your .svc file may have an error, are you using behavior extensions on the endpoint? You should post your endpoint and service config from the service.

Comment: So,forget about the last error i correct it.I hosted my service on IIS, and it's ok.but my problem when I host the ClientProject there is an error: [WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]and 
[EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:1695/Service1.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.]

Comment: take the URL that opens the service locally and paste it into a browser running on your test machine, change localhost to the correct server name, does it work?

Comment: I just saw that the error message says "localhost", are you hosting the client project on the same machine as the service?, otherwise you need the server name in there. Also your client config refers to localhost, that is probably the problem (unless client and server are on the same machine)

Comment: Finally Iresolved my problem, but know when i call var obj=client.MyMethode1(); obj is null.So how can I correct that please??

Comment: You should post the resolution of your problem as an answer.